# How to programmatically create a type def cluster in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I want to load data from a word file, convert it to a cluster, save the cluster as a type defined control and then save the control as an INI file.

It will then be possible to reuse the control for user input and the INI file will be scanned and dumped to a database.

The data will consist of variables of a known type, e.g. string, int, double, list, etc.

Is there a way to create an autosized type def cluster in LabVIEW?

Comment: Yes VI scripting is the method to do that.

Comment: @TonPlomp thanks Ton, reviewing my open questions.  Do you want to put in VI scripting as an answer so that I can accept it?